# ¿Porqué Ajax recibe una respuesta JSON desde PHP que incluye etiquetas HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Estoy intentando retornar una respuesta de un array en formato JSON desde PHP hacia JS a través de AJAX, pero por alguna razón en la respuesta se incluyen etiquetas HTML. cabe resaltar que en otro proyecto funciona bien, y ya me aseguré de no imprimir algo adicional en mis archivos PHP (lo que daña la respuesta JSON).

Si incluyo el **dataType: "json"** en AJAX, la petición falla. si no lo incluyo me retorna lo que describí anteriormente.

Esta es mi petición ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"ajax/usersAjax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    }).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
            console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
        }
});
```

Este es mi archivo PHP (el array **$response** está ahí porque creía que había algún error en **$rta**, así que quise asegurarme de que el json_encode() si recbiera un array):

```
<?php
require_once "../controller/userController.php";
require_once "../model/user.php";
class UsersAjax{
    
    function login($username, $password){
        $rta =  UserController::login($username, $password);
        $response = [
            "code" => 0,
            "msg" => "success"
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    function register($data){
        UserController::save($data);
    }
    
}

$ajax = new UsersAjax();

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    // lOGIN
    if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){
        $ajax->login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
    }

}

?>
```

Esta es la respuesta que obtengo cuando no incluyo el **dataType: "json"** en la petición:

```
<br />
<font size='1'>
    <table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5">
                <span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\TallerActasPhp\controller\userController.php on line 
                <i>59</i>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.4383</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>410912</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td>
            <td title='C:\xampp\htdocs\TallerActasPhp\ajax\usersAjax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\usersAjax.php
                <b>:</b>0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.4441</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>455272</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>UsersAjax->login( 
                <span>$username = </span>
                <span>&#39;user&#39;</span>, 
                <span>$password = </span>
                <span>&#39;pas&#39;</span> )
            </td>
            <td title='C:\xampp\htdocs\TallerActasPhp\ajax\usersAjax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\usersAjax.php
                <b>:</b>26
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.4442</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>455272</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>UserController::login( 
                <span>$username = </span>
                <span>&#39;user&#39;</span>, 
                <span>$password = </span>
                <span>&#39;pas&#39;</span> )
            </td>
            <td title='C:\xampp\htdocs\TallerActasPhp\ajax\usersAjax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\usersAjax.php
                <b>:</b>7
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</font>
{"code":0,"msg":"success"}
```

Como pueden ver, la última línea de la respuesta si es el array en formato JSON, pero incluye todas las etiquetas HTML al principio. Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: En el html te está indicando un error de acceso a un índice de array, cuando hay un booleano. Mira el usercontroller.php, en la línea 59. Te está devolviendo html porque salta ese warning, y ese warning se presenta como html.

Comment: Gracias, me faltaba validar que el usuario existiera en la base de datos. Al consultar un usuario que no esté registrado en la base de datos retornaba false y por ende no podía acceder a los índices de username y password respectivamente para iniciar la sesión. En verdad muchas gracias.